# Error compiling with GCC using pty

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pty

I'm messing with the pty with C, but for some reason the code doesnt compiles

```
#include <pty.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int fd;
    ptyfork(&fd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}
```

I compiled with -lutil, and outputs the next error:

```
gcc -lutil test3.c -o test3
/tmp/ccgTfZvt.o: In function 'main':
test3.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `ptyfork'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing?

Note: im compiling in ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit

Edit: Tried `gcc test3.c -o test3 -lutil` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is `forkpty`, not `ptyfork`. See the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/openpty.3.html).

Comment: @Alejandro Garcia : Don't worry. Use `-Wall` for avoiding this kind of problems. With it you will get following kind of messages during compile: `implicit declaration of function ptyfork`.